# Добавлении модуля binfmt_misc.ko в ядро Android

Tags: android, kernel, модули

Опыта в сборке ядер у меня крайне мало. Заранее спасибо всем, кто читает.

Нужно добавить модуль `binfmt_misc.ko` в ядро `Android`.

- Устройство: OnePlus One
- [Исходники ядра](https://github.com/ResurrectionRemix-Devices/android_kernel_oneplus_msm8974)
- Android NDK - android-ndk-r14b.

---

Собираю ядро(командой `make`), установив в `kernel/.config :`

```
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_BINFMT_MISC=m
```

Затем модули(не знаю, собираются ли они сразу, при выполнении make)

```
make modules
```

Собираю `boot.img`
Прошиваю через `fastboot` - все работает, и в настройках отображается время сборки(значит все хорошо).

Затем через `adb` с рутом перемонтирую `/system`, разрешив запись.
Заливаю в `/system/lib/modules файл kernel/fs/binfmt_misc.ko`.
И также от имени рута :
`insmod /system/lib/modules/binfmt_misc.ko`

---

***И ошибка :***

> insmod: failed to load binfmt_misc.ko: Bad addrress

*Команда* `modinfo` :

```
A0001:/system/lib/modules # modinfo binfmt_misc.ko
filename:       binfmt_misc.ko
license:        GPL
srcversion:     CC65003EC6BFAF280275F8C
depends:
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.4.112-Resurrected_Kernel-g41f44f0 SMP preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv7
```

Все это делал по инструкции от [Meefik](http://meefik.ru/blog/2015/02/05/linuxdeploy-build-kernel/).

Перерыл весь интернет, ничего не нашел. Не знаю что уже делать.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно (если есть возможность) пересобрать ядро и включить в него binfmt_misc как часть ядра, а не модулем. (Снова спасибо за помощь Meefik)